# how to avoid background-image overflowing div in css?

Tags: html, css, background

I've inspected the class "imagen_apartado" div and I saw that background is overflowing their container div and I don't really want this to happen. Could someone explain whats going on here?

```css
section.apartado,section.apartado a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:white;
}

section.apartado > div{
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(56, 61, 61);
  border-radius: 18px;
  font-size:0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 17px 9px 25px 9px;
}

section.apartado div div {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight:500;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 8px;
}

section.apartado div div p{
  padding-top: 13px;
}

section.apartado article#star_wars .imagen_apartado{
  background: url(https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1uatBqgNrXlpdBMwdgNitNVt0PU9g3nJ7) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  display: block;
  width:278px;
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Movies Drop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="apartado">
      Películas
      <div>
        <div>
          <article class="new" id="star_wars">
            <div class="imagen_apartado"></div>
            <p><a href="#">Star Wars 2</a></p>
          </article>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Q can you explain more what you want achieve and what is wrong exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, what Richard said.

Assuming you mean with overflowing, that the image get out of the div, and not be shown fully:

With

```
background-size: cover;
```

the image gets resized to cover the entire container. This can lead to cutting or streching the image, in your case cutting it off i guess ?

If you want to make sure the full image is shown you can do

```
background-size: contain;
```

This makes sure the full image is shown within the container, no matter the size of the container.

You can read more about background-size here : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: i have more than one image displayed in a unique container (div without class) , i put only one to show you their behaviour, i try everything you said but i dont understand how to solve my problem

Comment: In your example snippet, i actually cant see anything overflowing. I am not quite sure what you mean, or what your exact problem is. Could you please try to explain more specific ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KIfCNd7TpXtNDu1DCFdz_kbj3Z2rsro1/view?usp=sharing

look at the dashed lines

Comment: Oh, its the 8px padding you have on section.apartado div div.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want your image to overflow from div put it in `<img>` tag